# How to style the choose file button only?

Tags: css, django, web-frontend

[Using django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njcgt.jpg)
I am using django to upload post on my website. I can do that but i want to style that choose file button too like in Facebook

Comment: Post some code to show how far you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute `for` of `html` to create a button you want then hidden element . See example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer! It would be even better if you included the code using a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of linking to it externally :)

Comment: i actually did the same but there is one problem though.When we click image ,it won't show the name or any sign that you have clicked an image

Comment: @BishalRaEe attribute `for` just apply for `<label>` and `<output>` tag. You should set `<label>` tag outside your `<img>` tag. Then set attribute `for` in `<label>` tag.